# Wrapper for all audio on android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I would like to apply a custom filter on all audio played, is there a way to apply a listener to all the systems audio playback (ringtones, alarms, music)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from an Android SDK application. You could create your own custom build of the Android OS that has the changes you wish, then put that build into a ROM mod that you install on your device.